# Simple for loop in pandas

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have a simple indexing question with respect to pandas. 
I would like to make a simple for loop to go over numbers 1 to 5. 
I'm having trouble with pandas indexing in how to do this (although I'm sure its simple!)

My rough code:

```
def averaged_rel_track(current_tracks, rel_values):

    current_tracks['rel_values']=rel_values
    current_tracks=current_tracks.set_index('candidate')

    #I would like this line to loop over numbers 1 to 5
    b_1= current_tracks.rel_values.loc['1']
```

What I have tried:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    b=current_tracks.rel_values.iloc[i]

for i in range (1, 6):
    b = current_tracks.rel_values[i]

for i in range (1, 6):
   b=current_tracks.rel_values['i']
```

and various other similar variations (including `.ix, .iloc, .loc`)

Comment: Looping over an index is a last resort. Can you give the bigger picture? (What are you trying to do?) There is likely some vectorized method to do it more succinctly, and faster.

Comment: I thought it was slow, but I never new a better way to do it! (Newbie) hans answer below has another way to do it which I assume is much better? Basically I have a data frame of 3 columns, one of which is called `'candidate'` and it is reapting range of 1, 5. Basically I want to select all the values that are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, in turn.

Comment: I'm thinking bigger picture yet, but maybe this is beyond the scope of your question. Presumably, you are doing something with each of those values (1, 2, 3, 4), and my question is, what are you doing?

Comment: I'm taking a rolling average of all the data which corresponds to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Perhaps ``pd.concat([pd.rolling_mean(grp) for _, grp in current_tracks.groupby(rel_values)])``, depending on exactly what you mean. Consider opening a new question with a sample of your data and a sample of your desired output. There is definitely an easy way to do this, maybe in one line.

Comment: But +1 for showing what you have tried so far. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Your first try does not look too bad; I think you could use:

```
for i in range(5):
    b = current_tracks.rel_values.iloc[i] # by standard 0-based sequence index
```

or

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    b = current_tracks.rel_values.loc[i] # by 1-based track number
```

But you probably want to avoid 'for i in range(...)', which is not pythonic:

```
for b in current_tracks.rel_values.loc[1:5]: # or .iloc[:5]
    ...
```

Note that .loc[1:5] *includes* the last index value, while .iloc does not.  That's more intuitive than it sounds, since .iloc uses standard python indexing, while .loc supports any kind of application-specific indices, and it might not be possible to "increment" the end index in non-integer cases.

Comment: thanks for the help Hans. However, I'm wondering is there an issue with the `' '`? As if i add quotation marks when just using a single value i.e. `'1'` it works, but does not with out the quotation.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, .loc supports any kind of application-specific index, which includes strings.  I don't know how you created your DataFrame, and why the type appears to be strings (object), but maybe something like this helps: `df.index = pandas.Index(df.index.values.astype(int))`

Comment: data frame is imported from csv, then one of the columns is set as the index. this column is recurring 1-5. will try that, thanks

Comment: Actually, changing column / index types is better done the pandas way directly: `df.index = df.index.astype(int)`